# How to find if first character is an underscore?

Tags: php, wordpress

I tried this

```
foreach ($categories as $category) {
  if( $category[0] === '_'  ) {
    $option .= '<option>'.$category->name.'</option>';
  }
}
```

But gives me

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type WP_Term as array

I tried to use `implode()`

```
foreach ($categories as $category) {
  $string = implode($category);
  if( $category[0] === '_'  ) {
    $option .= '<option>'.$category->name.'</option>';
  }
}
```

But gives me

> Warning: implode(): Argument must be an array
>
> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type WP_Term as array

**UPDATE**

```
var_dump($categories);


array(1) { 
    [5]=> object(WP_Term)#999 (16) {
        ["term_id"]=> int(1) 
        ["name"]=> string(13) "Uncategorized" 
        ["slug"]=> string(13) 
        "uncategorized" 
        ["term_group"]=> int(0) 
        ["term_taxonomy_id"]=> int(1) 
        ["taxonomy"]=> string(8) "category" 
        ["description"]=> string(0) "" 
        ["parent"]=> int(0) 
        ["count"]=> int(9) 
        ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" 
        ["cat_ID"]=> int(1) 
        ["category_count"]=> int(9) 
        ["category_description"]=> string(0) "" 
        ["cat_name"]=> string(13) "Uncategorized" 
        ["category_nicename"]=> string(13) "uncategorized" 
        ["category_parent"]=> int(0) 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Show your WP query.

Comment: Seems to me you're not dealing with a string. If I had to guess, I'd say it's a `WP_Term`, whatever that is. Try converting it to a string if you want to do a string comparison on it.

Comment: @miken32 is it not what i've tried with implode?

Comment: `implode()` is for arrays. As the error message says.

Comment: ehmm how would I convert it into a string then? @miken32

Comment: I'd suggest looking at the documentation for whatever kind of object you're dealing with. Many objects have a method to convert to a string, if it's reasonable to do so – depends on the object.

Comment: Also, while it's possible to use array syntax for extracting characters from strings, it's not a good idea. It confuses the code and makes it unclear what type of variable you're dealing with. Use `substr`.

Comment: @rob.m do `var_dump($categories);` and add the output in your question. You will get correct answer then only

Comment: @AlivetoDie updated the question

Comment: First character of *what* is an `_`? There are multiple strings in a category object...

Comment: had to tell wordpress to show categories even if empty, that's why i could only see one cat on the var_dump() so     `$args = array('hide_empty' => 0);
    $categories = get_categories($args);` then the accepted answer for the underscore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
foreach ($categories as $category) {
  if($category->name[0] == '_'){
    $option .= '<option>'.$category->name.'</option>';
  }
}
```

Comment: is it the first character of the name that you are wanting to check is an underscore? or something else?

Comment: i have updated the question with a var_dump of $categories

Comment: actually this works, I had to tell wp to show categories even if they were empty, why did they give you a downvote tho?

Comment: have edited my code to be full example merged with yours

Comment: this works     `foreach ($categories as $category) {
      if($category->name[0] == '_'){
        $option .= '<option>'.$category->name.'</option>';
      }
    }`